# ¿Por qué solo me muestra el valor mas reciente? PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli, sql

Hago una consulta php y simplemente me muestra el valor más reciente, la idea sería que me mostrara todos.
Ya he intentado dejar el codigo abierto, es decir cerrar php pero sin cerrar los corchetes, luego el html y luego poner otro php con los corchetes de cierre. Pero no funciona y no sé qué más puedo hacer, he intentado con varios tutoriales de youtube y leyendo errores parecidos en esta y otras páginas pero nada me funciona. Siempre me muestra así aunque haya intentado ya con diferentes códigos. Por favor, ayúdenme.

```
<?php 
if($db){
$consulta="SELECT * FROM posts";
$resultado = mysqli_query($db, $consulta);
if($resultado){
    while($row1= $resultado->fetch_array()){
        $titulo = $row1['titulo'];
        $creador = $row1['creador'];
        $creacion = $row1['creacion'];
    }
}
}

<div id="lista"style=" position: fixed;left: 20%; bottom: 3%;background-color:white; width: 58%;height: 82%; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 4px 6px   rgba(205,205,205,0.6);
">
<h2><?php echo$titulo;?></h2>
<div>
<p>
<b></b><?php echo$creador;?><br>
<b><?php echo$creacion;?></b>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sí te fijas no le estás dando el tipo array a `$titulo`, `$creador` ni `$creador` por lo tanto solamente va a coger un valor, y pues recorre toda la variable `$row` y simplemente queda el último valor, eso primero, y segundo, en el html, simplemente le estás imprimiendo un valor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cómo ya te comenté no estás definiendoo los tipos de variable cómo array para guardar los múltiples datos que llegan en el `$row`, además de eso, tienes que imprimir cada uno de los datos que guardas, por lo tanto debes recorrer el array, quedaría así:

```
<div id="lista"style=" position: fixed;left: 20%; bottom: 3%;background-color:white; width: 58%;height: 82%; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 4px 6px   rgba(205,205,205,0.6);">
  <?php 
    if($db){
      $consulta="SELECT * FROM posts";
      $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $consulta);
      if($resultado){
          while($row1= $resultado->fetch_array()){
              echo "<div><h2> {$row1['titulo']}</h2>
              <div>
              <p>
              <b></b>{$row1['creador']} <br>
              <b> {$row1['creacion']}</b>
              </p>
              </div></div>";
          }
      }
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Cómo una sugerencia, podrías tomar los estilos que le das al `<div id="lista"` y en vez ponerlos todos como tal en la etiqueta puedes hacerlo con un apartado `CSS`, podría quedar así:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #lista{
    position: fixed;
    left: 20%; 
    bottom: 3%;
    background-color:white; 
    width: 58%;height: 82%; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 4px 6px   rgba(205,205,205,0.6);
  }
</style>
```

Por lo tanto simplemente pones el `div` así:

```
<div id="lista">
```

Alguna duda o sugerencia me la planteas, ojalá te sirva.

Comment: Tu respuesta marea demasiado la perdiz. ¿Para qué guardar los datos en varios array para luego imprimirlos de inmediato? ¿Por qué no imprimir dentro del primer `while? Además, la respuesta ignora aspectos básicos de HTML, como meter un montón de `div` dentro de un bucle. En separar elementos que son relacionados usando un `h2` y las partes de ese `h2` dentro de un `div`

Comment: Pues primero sería como para no tener tanto que modificarle al código, sí ya tiene una estructura formada pues prefiero que la mantega y moldearsela de tal manera que quede funcional

Comment: Yo creo que en las respuestas se pueden sugerir mejoras, sobre todo cuando apreciamos que el OP está implementando malas prácticas. A veces una respuesta sobre algo puede servir para ayudar a mejorar otros aspectos. Aquí no hay por qué guardar los datos, porque es evidente que se necesita imprimirlos ahí mismo. Otra cosa sería si necesitara los datos para pasarlos a otra parte o para devolverlos con `return` desde una función, pero no parece ser el caso aquí. El código no está optimizado, sobrecarga la memoria, primero guardando y luego imprimiendo.

Comment: Listo, yo creo que así está mucho mejor, solamente trato que sigan como familiarizados con las cosas que llevan haciendo para que no se confundan mucho cuando les hagan cambios drásticos, pero sí tienes razón

Comment: Gracias, esta me sirvió :)

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido, suerte con tu proyecto, saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Apoyando lo que dice @DaxTter77, lo escribo aquí porque me resulta más sencillo poner código. Básicamente te falta incrustar el html dentro del bucle (while) más o menos así:

```
while ($row1= $resultado->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <h2><?= $row1['titulo'] ?></h2>
    <div>
      <p>
        <b></b><?= $row1['creador'] ?><br>
        <b><?= $row1['creacion'] ?></b>
      </p>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Si con tu versión de php esto no te funciona `<?= $row1['titulo'] ?>`, cambialo por `<?php echo $row1['titulo']; ?>`

Comment: No es correcto esto. Si hay mil filas vas a crear mil `div` Las etiquetas `div` deberían estar fuera del `while`

Comment: Si en tu código agregaras donde debería abrir y cerrar el `<div id="lista"`, podrías demostrar que @A.Cedano está equivocado.

Comment: @Marcos por lógica el `<div id="lista">` debería ser el contenedor de toda la lista, o sea de todas las filas que se van a imprimir, por tanto, debería abrirse antes del `while` y cerrarse después del `while`, teniendo así un solo `div`. Las tres respuestas dadas hasta ahora ignoran aspectos básicos de HTML.

Comment: Pues se puede tener un contenedor para total guardar toda la información y un div para tener cada una de las filas separadas, y ya sí se les mete css pues tomarían una forma distinta en el cómo se ven, de igual manera diría yo que por lo tanto lo único que no están bien es no haber colocado el `<div id="lista"`

Comment: @Marcos las normas de HTML dicen claramente que no puede haber elementos con id repetidos. Ese HTML no validaría y si le incorporas código Javascript para alcanzar elementos por el id el código podría tener un comportamiento erróneo.

Comment: @A.Cedano, estamos hablando de lo mismo, pero por lo visto no nos entendemos. Esta respuesta no esta mal, al menos no lo parece. Si incluyera el `<div id="lista"` dentro del `while`, entonces ahí te daría la razon.

Comment: @Marcos yo entendí que decías poner el `<div id="lista> dentro del `while` ¿? Lo cual sería un error. Tratándose de una lista, puede haber un solo `div` que encierre a toda la lista y si se quiere aplicar algún estilo, se puede hacer alcanzando los elementos `p` por ejemplo. A eso me refiero cuando digo que se ignoran algunos aspectos relativos a HTML.

Answer (score 2):

El código HTML debería estar dentro del loop while. Sino en la última pasada del while setea el último valor que tomó de la base, y luego al generar el HTML usa esos valores:

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
if ($db) {
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $consulta);
    if ($resultado) {
        while ($row1 = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
            $i = 0;
            $titulo = $row1['titulo'];
            $creador = $row1['creador'];
            $creacion = $row1['creacion'];
            ?>
            <div id="lista-<?=$i++; ?>" style=" position: fixed;left: 20%; bottom: 3%;background-color:white; width: 58%;height: 82%; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 4px 6px   rgba(205,205,205,0.6);">
                <h2><?php echo $titulo; ?></h2>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <b></b><?php echo $creador; ?><br>
                        <b><?php echo $creacion; ?></b>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Este código va a producir un HTML erróneo. ¿Por qué metes un elemento `div` por cada fila, además con el miso `id`. Esto es incorrecto desde el punto de vista de HTML.

Comment: Cierto, gracias. Ahí edite el ID para que lo vaya cambiando.

Comment: Puede haber un `div` en cada fila o no.. la verdad que no mire los estilos. Pero así al menos debería funcionar.

Comment: Así está mejor. Saludos.